# Angular directives change color

Tags: angular

Create a custom directive that is going to set the font color value of the host component text to a random color value every 1 second. Colors are predefined in the state as an array: `['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'maroon'....etc]`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) you have instructions on how to create a new directive, also the example teaches changing the text background color (it's not the same as you asked, but you get the idea).

I made a sample:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[highlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.changeColor(el);
 }

 changeColor(el: ElementRef) {
   setInterval(() => {
    el.nativeElement.style.color = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colors.length)];
   }, 1000);
 }

}
```

Than to call it simply:

```
<h1 highlight>Example</h1>
```

Comment: And not even a +1 from the OP for making his homework. Sad. I was happy with it though!